# Rails 5 - Facebook authenticate error with omniauth-facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, omniauth-facebook

I get this error when I try use omniauth-facebook:
[image]

Follow my code:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are missing the confirmable database columns. Either add them or remove the devise `:confirmable` modules from your model.

Here are the steps to add the relevant code/schema if you did not install devise with the confirmable module initially: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-:confirmable-to-Users

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to uncomment the code in the devise migration that is needed for using the confirmable module.

```
  t.string   :confirmation_token
  t.datetime :confirmed_at
  t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
  t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable
```